# MSDEPLOY using MSBUILD from TFS 2010 -could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: iis, msbuild, msdeploy

I am getting following error.

ERR: could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Should I change any thing regarding https on IIS 7.5

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=151.143.180.16 
/p:DeployiisAppPath="DIAInternal/TestDIA" 
/p:Configuration=Debug 
/p:username= username  
/p:password=Password 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

Answer (score 0):

/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True  if you set that to false it would probably work.  The other thing you could do is install the bad cert in your trusted root certificate store.